# Compass filter out -moz vendor prefix

Tags: angularjs, sass, gruntjs, compass-sass, yeoman

Using **Yeoman** with **generator-angular-fullstack** for my project. The SCSS support is excellent however all my **-moz** prefixes are being filtered from the css result.

I've looked at the [**compass docs**](http://compass-style.org/help/tutorials/exclude_vendor_prefixes/) regrading Vendor Prefixes. The doc suggested to override the defaults vars:

```
$experimental-support-for-mozilla : true !default;
$experimental-support-for-webkit : true !default;
$support-for-original-webkit-gradients : true !default;
$experimental-support-for-opera : true !default;
$experimental-support-for-microsoft : true !default;
$experimental-support-for-khtml : true !default;
```

And I tried to add this code to my main.scss with no luck ... moz prefixes are still being removed.
I looked for another config file with no luck.

What am I missing?

Comment: do you have grunt autoprefixer in your grunt tasks?

Comment: Yes I do have it ... is that related?

Comment: i think so. at least autoprefixer adds the vendor prefixes for you, so you don't need to write a vendor prefix at all. i guess it removes also unecessary prefixes. may be you should remove autoprefixer from the task list (if the prefixes are still there you know it exactly) or you reconfiger the autoprofixer: https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer#browsers

Comment: I think you are right! post it as an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using grunt-autoprefixer the grunt task adds the vendor prefixes for you, so you don't need to write a vendor prefix at all. I guess it removes also unecessary prefixes. May be you should remove autoprefixer from the task list (if the prefixes are still there you know it exactly) or you reconfiger the autoprefixer: http://github.com/ai/autoprefixer#browsers